# Part-time bug with extension-methods

Tags: visual-studio, extension-methods

I'm currently dealing with a part-time (and annoying) bug with some extension methods in VB .NET (VS 2010 and VS 2008).

I have some client projects that use some extension methods from a "Framework" Project I created for general purpose.

However, sometime, when a try to start the solution, I get a long list of error saying the extension method "is not a member of" target object.

When this happen, I can rebuild the solution without getting any error but if I start the project again, the same error will be raised again.

So far I have 2 workaround

A) Go on the extension method definition, delete the  tag, compile (with error), put the tag back.

B) Close Visual Studio et re-open it.

Is there any betterway to handle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [active bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543198/vb-net-project-with-extensions-methods-generates-errors) for this problem at Connect.  There's a dire need for a repro, a project with specific steps to let them reproduce the issue in-house.  Perhaps you can help, it's what it will take to solve it or recommend a workaround.

EDIT: one late addition to this answer, since I've posted this there have been additional questions that note a problem with the IntelliSense parser behaving different from the compiler.  There's an issue with the multi-targeting feature, particularly in VS2010, triggered by the Client Profile option for .NET 4.  It is the default for a new project.  What goes wrong is adding an assembly reference that requires the full profile, commonly because of a dependency on System.Web.  You'll get a warning for that, but that's quickly blown away with a large number of errors.  The fix is to change the project's Framework Target from client to full.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently encountered this same issue.  My project would Build just fine but if I tried to use the Rebuilt option I would get the error about my extension methods not being found on the objects they were extending.

I have managed to fix this today by including an Import at the top of the classes using the Extension method.

So at the top of the file I actually have

Imports project_name.extension_module

I have no idea why this is required but it fixes the problem in my case.  I hope this helps somebody else that has wasted as much time with this as I have!

Liam

Answer (score 0):

A less time consuming work around than the two you listed is to "Rebuild Solution" instead of the normal Build Solution. This has always worked for me whenever I run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have something very similar. Call extensions merhod that extends type A. type is actually an instance of type B that implements interface C. interface C has a method with the same name as extension method.

Interface C declares method Foo
Class B inherits from A implements C

Static Class
   Static method Foo (this A)
    If A is C
      (A as C).Foo

When debugging on the line if A is C it actually calls Foo multiple times and you can step at assembly level and see it indicates it is doing the comparison. The way we demonstrate that the call is happen Foo executes a sql statement and we can see sql profiler executing the code in Foo.

Change A as C to reflection and bug goes away. Or use debugger hidden/step through and bug is masked. Also if you micro-step the sql profiler shows the query is getting called multiple times (before Foo is actually called) for each assembly statement.